# Trigger not firing when data updating replication

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two databases on different servers and I have implemented replication to sync data between both database.

I have some triggers on subscribe database and those are not firing when any change is made through replication.

Please suggest a solution for this.

```
Create TRIGGER [dbo].[Ins_SLab]
   ON  [dbo].[Slab] 
   AFTER Insert
AS 
BEGIN
Declare @ProductId int
set @ProductId =(select PurchaseProductID from Inserted)
set @ProductId =(select ProductID from dbo.PurchaseProduct where ID = @ProductId)
insert into tblTestTriger values('Hold Product Update',@ProductId)
End
Go
```

Comment: post some code from the triggers please.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you *don't* have the [`NOT FOR REPLICATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) option specified, which would be the most obvious reason.

But the second most obvious reason is that the trigger probably *is* firing. But because you've written your trigger to assume that it only applies to one row, it will only apply to one row in each batch of replicated rows.

What you need, instead, is to treat `inserted` as a table, and re-write your trigger to keep everything set-based throughout - if you're assigning to variables, you're doing it wrong.

```
insert into tblTestTriger --TODO: Explicit column list
select 'Hold Product Update',pp.ProductId
from inserted i
   inner join
    dbo.PurchaseProduct pp
   on i.PurchaseProduct = pp.ID
```